# Grouped barplot in excel

Tags: excel, bar-chart

Been looking for an answer to this question but as I found nothing I ask it here in hope of getting an answer. This is probably easy for most people.

I got three columns in excel where the first column has the values 1 OR 2 and the second column has the values 1 OR 2 and on the third column are reaction times for each subject (one row is a subject). So a subject can be either 1 or 2 on first column, either 1 or 2 on second column, and then their reaction time.

I want to do a clustered column plot. In the Y-axis I would like to have the third column (its reaction time in milliseconds). On the X-axis I would like to have two groups (take column one, where one group is 1 and the other is 2. Each group (1 and 2) will further be divided into two groups (second column, values 1 and 2). Those could be symbolized as two different colored bars within the two groups of the x-axis (what this second split reflects could be shown on a legend as color red and blue). If I mark all values and press "clustered column", the result is weird. And working with the stuff within the "select" button is like reading hieroglyphs.

(Unfortunately, I could not write how my data looks like because all numbers appears next to each other instead of having them as three columns.)

Answer (score 0):

Look into pivot Tables and get a chart from that.

1) select the table data(have headers for Group 1, Group2, and Reaction)
2) Insert--> Pivotchart
3) Put Group1 into the Axis fields
4) Put Group2 into the Axis fields below Group1
5) Put Reaction into the Values box.
6) Reaction will likely appear as Sum, so click Reaction and 'Value Field Settings'
7) Change to Average(I presume you want an average of reaction times...)
8) Play around with right-clicking the various areas of the chart to learn about formatting the chart...